# VBで起動したDOSプロンプトに表示されているテキスト（表示内容）の取得方法

Tags: vb.net, winapi

VisualBasic（.NetFramework4.0）Windows10でプログラミングをしております。

system.diagnostics.process.startでDOSプロンプト（CMD.EXE）を起動しその画面に表示されているテキストを取得（範囲選択＆コピーでクリップボード保存）したく思いますが、WindowsAPIでどのような関数を使用すれば良いのか検討が付きません。

起動したプロセスから取得したMainWindowHandleを対象とした、もしくは引数に取る関数ではないかと想像しているのですがご存知の方おられましたらお助けお願いできますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「表示されているテキスト」というのはバッチファイルなどから出力されたテキストですか？それともユーザーが入力したテキストですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
表示されているテキストとはDOS窓の中に表示されているテキストです。つまりコマンドプロンプト起動直後であればMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.と言う内容ですし、DIRコマンドをVBのプログラムから送信（この部分は完成しています）するとカレントディレクトリの内容がDOSプロンプトに表示されますのでそれを取得したいと言う意味になります。

Comment: [`OutputDataReceived`イベント](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)で取得する方法がありますが、試したところコマンドプロンプト上には表示されません。これでは意味がないですよね？

Comment: 説明が不十分で申し訳ございません。コマンドの送信自体はuser32.dllのSendMessageコマンドで目的のDOS窓のウインドウハンドル宛にメッセージを送信する事を想定していますので実際のDOS窓に表示されていないと想定と異なってしまいます。
自分が想定しているのはWindowsAPIを利用してウインドウハンドルを指定で目的のウィンドウの中身を範囲選択してコピーしてクリップボードに貼り付けるような操作が出来ればベストであると思っています。

Comment: 質問の補足情報はコメントのやりとりを追いかけなくても把握できるように質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: 完全なコピーではありませんが、
DOSコマンドの結果だけであれば、コマンドの最後に標準出力をファイルに書き出して似たことが出来ますよ。DOS窓の初期表示の取得とかは出来ませんが、
文字列として受け取れるのでかなり複雑なことも出来ます。　
ex) dir > 出力ファイル名.txt

Comment: 子プロセスの標準出力を読む方針はダメなのでしょうか。（その場合、デッドロックに注意するとか、回答といろいろな知見が集まると思います）

Comment: [ReadConsoleOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc429664.aspx)とその周辺のＡＰＩを使うのかなと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

まず、テキストをどう保持してどう描画するかはアプリケーションによって様々ですから、「ウィンドウハンドルを渡せばウィンドウに表示されているテキストを取り出せる」といった汎用的なAPIは存在しません。

cmd.exe をはじめとするコンソールアプリケーションの場合、例のウィンドウはWindowsが管理しているのでコンソールに表示されている文字を読み取るAPIもあります。ただし「現在のプロセスのコンソールウィンドウから読み取る」という形になるので、

- `AttachConsole()` で対象のプロセス（cmd.exeなど）のコンソールウィンドウにアタッチし、
- `GetStdHandle()` でスクリーンバッファのハンドルを取得し、
- `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()` でスクリーンバッファの大きさを調べ、
- `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` で任意の範囲の文字を読み取る

という流れになります。別のプロセスから読み取る際には `FreeConsole()` で切り離したうえで、上記と同じことを繰り返します。

参考： [コンソールへのアタッチ - EternalWindows](http://eternalwindows.jp/windevelop/console/console06.html)

---

ただこの場合、出力されたという通知は受けられないので定期的に確認する必要がありますし、どこからどこまでが新しい出力なのかも自分で判別する必要があります。改行と折り返しの区別もつきません。

「ボタンを押したらその時点での画面を取り込む」程度ならいいかもしれませんが、次のようなことをしたいなら標準入出力のリダイレクトの方が簡単かと思います。

- 自作のアプリからコンソールアプリとやり取りしたい
  ⇒ `process.StandardInput` に書き込んで `process.StandardOutput` から読みだす
- やり取りが画面に表示されるようにしたい
  ⇒ `StandardInput` `StandardOutput` を通る内容をテキストボックスなどに表示する
- ユーザーがコマンドを打てるようにしたい
  ⇒ テキストボックスにでも入力させて、 `StandardInput` に書き込む

<sub>（コンソールAPIを直接叩くアプリや、[出力がリダイレクトされているかどうかで挙動を変えるアプリ](https://superuser.com/q/352490/423291)の場合は別ですが。）</sub>

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
先の回答中の【コンソールに表示されている文字を読み取るAPIもあります】とはどのようなAPIになりますでしょうか？
コンソールの実行自体は元のVBアプリケーションから非同期で実行して読み取り自体をVBアプリケーションから行えばそのAPIが使えると言う事でよろしいでしょうか？お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: @ひこにゃん 「コンソールに表示されている文字を読み取るAPI」が回答に記載した `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` で、それを交えた実際の流れが回答に記載したものになります。cmd.exeを実行しておいて、任意のタイミングでこのAPIを使ってコンソール画面上の文字を読みだすことができます。（[C#での例](https://gist.github.com/unarist/6944cdc44aaf22b1a654)）

Answer (score 0):

ちょっと脱線しますが、こちらも参考になるかもしれません。

> ```
> Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>   Dim results As String
>   Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
>
>   'ComSpecのパスを取得する
>   psi.FileName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ComSpec")
>   '出力を読み取れるようにする
>   psi.RedirectStandardInput = False
>   psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
>   psi.UseShellExecute = False
>   'ウィンドウを表示しないようにする
>   psi.CreateNoWindow = True
>   'コマンドラインを指定（"/c"は実行後閉じるために必要）
>   psi.Arguments = "/c ping 192.168.1.1"
>   '起動
>   Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
>   '出力を読み取る
>   results = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
>   '出力された結果を表示
>   TextBox1.Text = results
>
>   'WaitForExitはReadToEndの後である必要がある
>   '(親プロセス、子プロセスでブロック防止のため)
>   p.WaitForExit()
> End Sub
> ```

ここから引用しました。
http://soudan1.biglobe.ne.jp/qa5873147.html

参考になりそうなページ
http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/standardoutput.html